# my session value immediate expires immediate in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

but also changed session time but its not working.

```
SqlCommand conb = new SqlCommand("select state from Registration where Aadhar='" + Session["adhar"].ToString().Trim() + "'", conn);                 
SqlDataAdapter daa = new SqlDataAdapter(conb);
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
daa.Fill(dt1);
```

Comment: Would need a lot more detail to understand what is going on.  Also accessing Session the way you are is really unsafe.  There are magic string issues here, and also no checking if the value exists.  I also recommend you paramatize your query to prevent SQL Injection.

Answer (score -1):

Use this in webconfig file

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState timeout="25"></sessionState>
 </system.web>
```